# Condensed comment lists should show first comments instead of highest-voted

Tags: discussion, comments

On some questions/answers, there are lots of comments (10+). The 'top' comment may be a response to a comment that isn't even displayed until you click on "Show **x** more comments".

I often start reading the comments without clicking on "Show x more comments" and find myself confused when I expand the comments, as I lose track of the position of the comments I've already read.

I wish the comments were always displayed chronologically -- the condensed list should consist only of the first *n* posts, regardless of the votes.

Perhaps a better algorithm could be created such that comments that include "@username" will only be displayed if username's previous post was also displayed.

Comment: Wait... are you saying that comments *are* sorted by upvotes, or are you saying that they *should* be? Because they're not and that's a bad idea. Chronological order and all that.

Comment: He's saying that *condensed lists* of comments **should not** be sorted by upvotes.

Comment: @AdamRackis, correct.

Comment: @Adam: But they're not re-sorted _currently_. /cc Uwat

Comment: meh comments are mostly noise anyway... especially comments on meta questions about comments

Comment: I'm having trouble following what's going on here. Are comments always sorted chronologically? And when there's a "show X more comments" link they're still sorted chronologically, but some of the low-scoring comments are just not displayed?

Comment: @CanSpice - *prior to* clicking the show X more comments, the comments are *not* sorted chronologically, so you'll see highly rated reply comments without seeing what they're replying too

Comment: @CanSpice, actually this is correct. Even in condensed lists the top rated comments are sorted chronologically, but I don't like the fact that some earlier (and low-scoring) comments aren't displayed.

Comment: See what I'm talking about? Adam says they're not sorted chronologically, Uwat says they are.

Comment: The only way to find out is to upvote this comment of mine heavily and add more noise until it either sorts higher or lower than lunboks' comment.

Comment: @sixlettervariables noise noise noise noise

Comment: @CanSpice - uwat is not explaining it well.  All of the highly-rated comments are sorted chronologically, but many of those highly rated comments are in response to *non* highly rated comments, which are not shown.  That's the point of the question.  Don't cut off low-rated comments, just show the first X comments in chronological order period

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yes, I understand that, but when you go and say "the comments are not sorted chronologically" (which is incorrect) you muddy the waters.

Comment: @Adam: they remain in chronological order. Consider a list of comments `{date, score}`: `[{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 2}, {4, 10}, {5, 0}, {6, 0}, {7, 1}, {8, 8}, {9, 15}, {10, 0}, {11, 0}, {12, 85}, {13, 0}, {14, 0}, {15, 1}, {16, 2}]`. When the list is condensed, we get: `[{4,10}, {8, 8}, {9, 15}, {12, 85}]` (length dependent on threshhold). The _order_ doesn't change.

Comment: @lulius - Sure.  I think we're saying the same thing -- your edit seems to make the question a bit clearer

Comment: @Adam: Yes; I just didn't understand what the heck you or Uwat were talking about until [your previous comment to CanSpice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126976/condensed-comment-lists-should-show-first-comments-instead-of-highest-voted#comment344647_126976) (which you posted while I was typing mine up).

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/comments-top-n-shown/

Comment: "We didn’t get to the user preference yet, but it’s coming" *suuuure*, we believe you... *really...*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like I've answered this before, but I can't find it. So here goes again: As was explained in the comments on this question, comments *are* always displayed chronologically, but when only the top *n* comments are shown, **comments are not *filtered* chronologically, the top voted comments are shown**.

I, for one, *vastly prefer* this way. Comments are second class citizens and we want to show only an overview of **the best** comments. *If you're reading a conversation thread you should always click* "SHow *n* more comments" *otherwise you're missing parts of the conversation.

Many people (like myself) **do not read** entire comment threads unless we have a reason to. A reason, for example, might be *one of the top comments which was shown in the overview*. Hence, the reason for this feature.

If this **really** bothers you (and others) maybe a userscript is in order. I've been known to write those if asked nicely; one which automatically shows all comments shouldn't be too difficult...

Actually it's really, really simple:

```
$('a.comments-link').click()
```

Stick that in a userscript and... smoke it? run it? install it? You get the idea...

Comment: *"Many people (like myself) do not read entire comment threads unless we have a reason to."* Case in point: the comment thread on this very question.